# cant install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I have meteor(0.8.2) project which work properly on ububtu 14.04 at my home. But, the same project at my work place fails to build. I am working on windows 7 machine and behind corporate proxy(which blocks all outgoing http requests). So, When i build this project it shows me following exception:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
csv-to-collection: updating npm dependencies -- comma-separated-values...
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `csv-to-collection`:
error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I am curious to know that can it be resolved by "unblocking" some port? or is there any other workaround for this issue?

Comment: Your corp proxy blocks _all_ outgoing HTTP? If so, you'll have to proxy your npm requests thru _some_ external proxy listening on _some_ port that your proxy/firewall will let thru. Or bring all packages to a local repo.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to unblock this with a port or something, (unless that port is 80 & 443, which is pretty much the internet)

Perhaps you could set up npm to use a web proxy

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Since meteor wraps around npm, it might help, though not sure.

From: http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy